# Swift: UITableView row items not hiding when hide that row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, collapsable

I have a table view class and three cell classes which I am using to populate 3 rows of table view.[screenshot of my table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrqSo.png)

I want to hide 2nd row whenever toggle button is off. when I tap on the toggle button the row gets collapsed but the cell item does not hide.[scrrenshot after tapping toggle button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPAFS.png)

here is my code:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row==0{
            let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellid", for: indexPath) as! toggleCell
            return cell

        }
        if indexPath.row==1{
            let cell1=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellid2", for: indexPath) as! oneButtonCell
            cell1.layer.backgroundColor=UIColor.purple.cgColor
            return cell1
        }
        else{
            let cell1=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellid1", for: indexPath)
            cell1.layer.backgroundColor=UIColor.green.cgColor
            return cell1
        }
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row==1{
            if istoggleOn==true{
                return 75
            }
            else{
            return 0
            }
        }
        else{
            return 75
        }
    }
}
class CellBase: UITableViewCell{
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style:style,reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func setupViews(){
        backgroundColor=UIColor.green
    }
}
class toggleCell:CellBase{

    let containerView=UIView()
    let label:UILabel={
        let label=UILabel()
        label.text="Toggle Button"
        label.textColor = .black
        label.font=UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 20)
        return label
    }()
    lazy var button:UISwitch={
            let toggle=UISwitch()
            toggle.isOn=true
            toggle.onTintColor=UIColor(red: 59/255, green: 178/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1)
            toggle.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleToggleAction), for: .valueChanged)
            return toggle
        }()
    @objc func handleToggleAction(sender:UISwitch){
         let parent = self.parentViewController as! ViewController

        if sender.isOn{
            print("on")
            parent.istoggleOn=true
            parent.tableView.beginUpdates()
            parent.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
        else{
            print("off")
            parent.istoggleOn=false
            parent.tableView.beginUpdates()
            parent.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
    override func setupViews(){
    addSubview(containerView)
    setupContainerView()

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-20-[v0]-20-|", views: containerView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-15-[v0]-15-|", views: containerView)
}
    func setupContainerView(){
}
class oneButtonCell:CellBase{
    let containerView:UIView={
        let view=UIView()
        view.layer.cornerRadius=10
        view.layer.borderColor=UIColor(red: 59/255, green: 178/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        view.layer.borderWidth=2
        return view
    }()
    let label:UILabel={
        let label=UILabel()
        label.text="SomeText"
        label.textColor = .black
        label.font=UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 20)
        return label
    }()
    lazy var button:UIButton={
           let button=UIButton()
            button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
            button.titleLabel?.font=UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 20)
            button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            button.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 59/255, green: 178/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
            let image=UIImage(named: "arrow")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
            button.imageView?.tintColor = .gray
            button.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(preferenceMenu), for: .touchUpInside)
            return button
        }()
    @objc func preferenceMenu(sender:UIButton){
        print("drop")
    }
    override func setupViews(){
        addSubview(containerView)
        setupContainerView()

        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-20-[v0]-20-|", views: containerView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-15-[v0(45)]-15-|", views: containerView)
    }
    func setupContainerView(){
}
}
```

I am doing everything programmatically. please help me how I can achieve this

Comment: where is your `numberOfRowsInSection` handler?

Comment: Handle this thing with numberOfRows in your tableView.Like if the toggle button is set to true then return 2 otherwise 3 in `numberOfRows:inSection()` method and similarly return the respective cell depending on the toggle statue in `cellForRowAt`

Comment: I am getting this error with this approach: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell's contents are showing because you made the row-height `0`... but this approach for showing/hiding a row (and the way you have setup your views) doesn't change the ***content*** of that cell.

So, the content is still *showing* because it is extending below the bounds of the cell.

There are other (arguably better) ways of showing/hiding rows, but sticking with your approach...

Change your `setupViews()` func in `class CellBase` to:

```
func setupViews(){

    // add this line
    self.clipsToBounds = true

    backgroundColor=UIColor.green

}
```

---

**Edit**

Since the code from the original post was not complete, I forgot to note that each custom cell class should probably be including a call to `super` in its `setupViews()` func:

```
override func setupViews(){
    // adding this line will allow you to put common setup tasks
    // in the setupViews() func in CellBase class
    super.setupViews()

    // do additional setup tasks that are specific to this cell class
    addSubview(containerView)
    setupContainerView()

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-20-[v0]-20-|", views: containerView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-15-[v0]-15-|", views: containerView)
}
```

Comment: its not working when I add this to cell base class but when I add in override setupViews func of oneButtonCell class it worked. Thank you for your help can you please tell me what can be other ways of showing/hiding the rows?

Comment: @FazeelaIqbal - See the edit to my answer. Since your original code was incomplete, I had added a couple things (like adding the switch to the view in your `toggleCell` class). As to other ways to show/hide rows, it depends on what you are ultimately trying to do. For your specific (simple) example, this approach works - although it would be better to use a closure / callback than giving the cell a reference to the controller. A little searching will find other approaches which may be better, depending on your needs.